# How do I use Google Maps JS API with Inertia.js server-side rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, inertiajs

I'm trying to set up server-side rendering for my Vue.js SPA built using Inertia and Laravel. Whenever I try to load a page including a Map, I get an error like the following from the SSR server process:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <Map errors= {} venues= [
  {
    name: 'Some Hall',
    lat: '45.492480',
    lng: '0.336327',
    address: '1 Interesting Street',
    url: 'http://localhost/venues/some-hall'
  },
**** Lots more prop data elements here ****
 }
] key=null >
TypeError: Loader is not a constructor
    at setup (file:///var/www/html/bootstrap/ssr/ssr.js:510:20)
    at _sfc_main$4.setup (file:///var/www/html/bootstrap/ssr/ssr.js:613:25)
    at callWithErrorHandling (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:156:18)
    at setupStatefulComponent (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7244:25)
    at setupComponent (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7205:36)
    at renderComponentVNode (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:614:15)
    at renderVNode (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:743:14)
    at renderComponentSubTree (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:698:7)
    at renderComponentVNode (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:631:12)
    at renderVNode (/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:743:14)
```

The site is using composer packages `laravel/framework@10.28.0` and `inertiajs/inertia-laravel@0.6.11`. My `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.16.2",
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.12",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.4.0",
        "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.3.7",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "vue": "^3.3.6"
    }
}
```

My `resources/js/app.js` looks like this:

```js
import {createSSRApp, h} from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true });
        return pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`];
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createSSRApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

And my `resources/js/ssr.js` looks like this:

```js
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import createServer from '@inertiajs/vue3/server'
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer'
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue'

createServer(page =>
    createInertiaApp({
        page,
        render: renderToString,
        resolve: name => {
            const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true })
            return pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]
        },
        setup({ App, props, plugin }) {
            return createSSRApp({
                render: () => h(App, props),
            }).use(plugin)
        },
    }),
)
```

Searches for answers so far led me down the track of whether this is a CommonJS/ESM compatibility issue (although I don't fully understand this), so when importing the `js-api-loader` module, I've tried both of the following:

```js
// Initially this...

import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";

// And also this...

import * as GMaps from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader'
const { Loader } = GMaps
```

Neither seems to make any difference. As far as I understand, the second option is to do with handling CJS modules, but I don't think the Google module is using the CommonJS standard, as far as I can tell.

The code in my `*.vue` pages that seems to cause the error is:

```js
const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: env.google_maps_api_key,
    version: "weekly",
    libraries: ['places'],
});
```

Would really appreciate some guidance!

### Update

I put some `console.log()` lines in where the error is being reported:

```js
    const { Loader } = GMaps;
    const props = __props;
console.log(GMaps);
console.log(Loader);
    const loader = new Loader({
      apiKey: env.google_maps_api_key,
      version: "weekly",
      libraries: ["places"]
    });
```

The output is:

```
[Module: null prototype] {
  default: {
    LoaderStatus: {
      '0': 'INITIALIZED',
      '1': 'LOADING',
      '2': 'SUCCESS',
      '3': 'FAILURE',
      INITIALIZED: 0,
      LOADING: 1,
      SUCCESS: 2,
      FAILURE: 3
    },
    DEFAULT_ID: '__googleMapsScriptId',
    Loader: [Function: o]
  }
}
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved this for now, but I don't really understand what's going on. I'd be happy to change the accepted answer if someone can provide a better explanation of what's going on here in terms of module types, imports, node and the browser.

Essentially, my working import now looks like this:

```js
import * as GMaps from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';
const { Loader } = GMaps.default ?? GMaps;
```

It seems that in one instance (the browser, I think?), the module is imported as an object containing the exported properties of the module (i.e. `{ LoaderStatus: ..., DEFAULT_ID: ..., Loader: ... }` and in another (node on the server, I think) the module is imported wrapped in a parent object's `default` property (i.e. `{ default: { LoaderStatus: ..., DEFAULT_ID: ..., Loader: ... }}`). I'm not sure why.

The solution above essentially uses the `??` operator to first try to deconstruct the `default` property, if it exists, and if not, fall back to the deconstructing the parent object itself.

[These](https://github.com/antfu/vite-ssg/issues/266#issuecomment-1605275438) [links](https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/broken-npm-package#named-export-not-found) were helpful in getting me this far.